# First key of php associative array returns undefined index when parsed from CSV

Tags: php

I am having trouble accessing the first index of an associative array when parsing from a csv.

CSV:

```
ID,COLOR
1,Red
2,Green 
3,Blue
```

PHP:

```php
function associative_array_from_csv($csv)
{
    $rows   = array_map('str_getcsv', file($csv));
    $header = array_shift($rows);
    $array  = array();

    foreach($rows as $data) {
        $array[] = array_combine($header, $data);
    }

    return $array;
}

$colors = associative_array_from_csv($csv);
```

Now `$colors` returns:

```php
[
    [
        "ID"    => "1",
        "COLOR" => "Red",
    ],
    [
        "ID"    => "2",
        "COLOR" => "Green ",
    ],
    [
        "ID"    => "3",
        "COLOR" => "Blue",
    ],
];
```

But if I try to access the `ID` of any color:

```php
$colors[0]["ID"]    // returns undefined index: ID
$colors[0]["COLOR"] // returns "Red"
```

If I loop over the colors I can access the `ID` like so:

```php
foreach($colors as $color) 
{ 
    print_r(reset($color)); // Prints the ID 
}
```

But why I can't access it directly like `$colors[0]["ID"]`?

Thanks

Comment: is it `$color` or `$colors`?

Comment: Works for me: https://3v4l.org/HTcTI, please check.

Comment: Try trimming your array keys, there may be some weird characters in there.

Comment: @AmrAly It's `$colors`, I've updated that last line.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. The problem was that Excel adds a hidden character to the first cell in the document, for encoding UTF-8 BOM.

I could see this when running:

```
var_dump(json_encode($array));
```

This would return:

```
string(312) "[{"\ufeffemail":"test@me.com","firstName":"import","lastName":"test"},{"\ufeffemail":"test@comcast.net","firstName":"import","lastName":"test"}]"
```

To remove the \ufeff character, I did:

```
$header = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $header);
```

In this case, that would be:

```
function associative_array_from_csv($csv)
{
    $rows   = array_map('str_getcsv', file($csv));
    $header = array_shift($rows);
    $header = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $header);
    $array  = array();

    foreach($rows as $data) {
        $array[] = array_combine($header, $data);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: This works very well. You saved my night. I'm so confused why my first index is undefined. Big thanks to questionnaire and you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

header = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $header);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Missing $ at begging :)